# end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel, mount

Recently turned on my Lenovo Yoga laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 and got an error saying it was unable to read drive hd0. It then ran through some lines and ended with the title. I am very new to running a linux distro on my computer, and I do not know what I am doing. If you need any other information from me please let me know. I may have to ask how to get that info though.

Answer (score 0):

Has a similar problem just now. Apparently your /boot partition is out of free space which causes this problem when updating to a new kernel. Select manually an older kernel in the grub menu so you can boot. Then to clean up /boot use `sudo apt-get autoremove` or delete old kernel files manually so you keep at least one working one. Then add the new kernel to grub:
`update-initramfs -u -k version`, where `version` is the new kernel version. Then run `update-grub` to update the grub file and it should boot again.